# Configure remote tests on Databricks with the Testing Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, databricks, vscode-extensions, databricks-connect

I'm currently testing the Databricks VSCode extension.

I find it way easier to use for developers than dbx because of its native integration.
I'd like to test its integration with the "Test Lab" extension (cf image below)

[image]

I managed to make my tests work with a local Spark. I'd really like to know if this is possible to make this extension work with the tests run remotely on Databricks clusters.

The goal is to see the tests in success/fail not in the console but in the interface (cf image below)

[image]

From what I search, it doesn't seem to have a native integration for this. Am I correct ? Is there a custom way to do it by modifying the configuration of the tests ?